# Oracle SQL conditional ranking

Tags: sql, oracle, ranking, rank

In my query, I am doing multiple types of ranking and for one of ranking types, I want to rank the row only if certain column is not null. Else I don't want ranking to happen.

For example here's a sample table:

```
+------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
| col1 |    col2    |    col3    | rank 1 | rank 2 |
+------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
| a    | 2018-01-20 | 2018-03-04 |      2 | 2      |
| a    | 2018-01-24 | 2018-04-04 |      1 | 1      |
| b    | 2018-01-02 | 2018-05-03 |      1 | 1      |
| c    | 2017-01-02 | 2017-05-08 |      3 | 2      |
| d    | 2016-05-24 | null       |      1 | null   |
| c    | 2018-02-05 | 2018-05-03 |      2 | 1      |
| c    | 2018-07-28 | null       |      1 | null   |
+------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
```

rank1 is calculated alright based on `partition by col1 order by col2 desc`
rank 2 should be calculated the same way, but only when when col3 is null, else it should be null.

How can I achieve both ranks in a single query? I tried to use case statement for rank2, but it skips the ranking when col3 is null,

Comment: what is your expect rank if the `col3` is `null`

Comment: I want the rank to be calculated based on col 2 date, but only when the column 3 is not null. If column 3 is null then rank should not be calculated, and hence should be null.

Comment: Ok you can try my answer :) @Sejal Parikh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand corrcly, you can try to use `CASE WHEN` with `sum` *window function*

`CASE WHEN` check `col3` isn't `null` do accumulate else display `NULL`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  col1 VARCHAR(5),
  col2 DATE,
  col3 DATE
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ( 'a' , to_date('2018-01-20','YYYY-MM-DD') , to_date('2018-03-04','YYYY-MM-DD'));  
INSERT INTO T VALUES ( 'a' , to_date('2018-01-24','YYYY-MM-DD') , to_date('2018-04-04','YYYY-MM-DD'));  
INSERT INTO T VALUES ( 'b' , to_date('2018-01-02','YYYY-MM-DD') , to_date('2018-05-03','YYYY-MM-DD'));  
INSERT INTO T VALUES ( 'c' , to_date('2017-01-02','YYYY-MM-DD') , to_date('2017-05-08','YYYY-MM-DD'));  
INSERT INTO T VALUES ( 'd' , TO_DATE('2016-05-24','YYYY-MM-DD') , null);  
INSERT INTO T VALUES ( 'c' , TO_DATE('2018-02-05','YYYY-MM-DD') , to_date('2018-05-03','YYYY-MM-DD'));  
INSERT INTO T VALUES ( 'c' , TO_DATE('2018-07-28','YYYY-MM-DD') , null);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1.*,
    rank() OVER(partition by col1 order by col2 desc) rank1,
    (CASE WHEN COL3 IS NOT NULL THEN
       SUM(CASE WHEN COL3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(partition by col1 order by col2 desc)
    ELSE
       NULL
    END) rank2
FROM T t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4ae1/16/0)**:

```
| COL1 |                 COL2 |                 COL3 | RANK1 |  RANK2 |
|------|----------------------|----------------------|-------|--------|
|    a | 2018-01-24T00:00:00Z | 2018-04-04T00:00:00Z |     1 |      1 |
|    a | 2018-01-20T00:00:00Z | 2018-03-04T00:00:00Z |     2 |      2 |
|    b | 2018-01-02T00:00:00Z | 2018-05-03T00:00:00Z |     1 |      1 |
|    c | 2018-07-28T00:00:00Z |               (null) |     1 | (null) |
|    c | 2018-02-05T00:00:00Z | 2018-05-03T00:00:00Z |     2 |      1 |
|    c | 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-08T00:00:00Z |     3 |      2 |
|    d | 2016-05-24T00:00:00Z |               (null) |     1 | (null) |
```

Comment: This does work! Can you explain me the logic behind this? I want to understand how did you think of using sum instead of rank here.

Comment: To check the `col3` is or isn't `NULL` if `col3` is `NULL` do accumulate otherwise only display `NULL` didn't do anything.

Comment: I would use `SUM` with `CASE WHEN` instead of `RANK` because of if you use `RANK`  will be accumulate  when the col3 is `null`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want:

```
select count(col3) over (partition by col1 order by col2 desc)
```

Note that this is equivalent to `row_number()` rather than `rank()`.  For your data these are equivalent.