# Oracle - generate a running number by group

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to generate a running number / group sequence inside a select statement for a group of data.
For example

```
Group   Name   Sequence
1       a      1
1       b      2
1       c      3
2       d      1
2       e      2
2       f      3
```

So for each group the sequence should be a running number starting with 1 depending on the order of column"Name".
I already pleayed around with Row_Number() and Level but I couldn't get a solution.
Any idea how to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51895196/oracle-sql-conditional-ranking - This link may useful to you

Comment: Can you add a table, what you already played around with, the results, and how it's not working because of what you'd like to see instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytic functions help.

```
SQL> with test (cgroup, name) as
  2    (select 1, 'a' from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'b' from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'c' from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'd' from dual union all
  6     select 2, 'e' from dual union all
  7     select 2, 'f' from dual
  8    )
  9  select cgroup,
 10         name,
 11         row_number() over (partition by cgroup order by name) sequence
 12  from test
 13  order by cgroup, name;

    CGROUP N   SEQUENCE
---------- - ----------
         1 a          1
         1 b          2
         1 c          3
         2 d          1
         2 e          2
         2 f          3

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Perfect, "partition" was the missing link, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
       "Group",
       Name,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "Group" ORDER BY Name) AS Sequence
FROM   table;
```

Comment: This won't work if there are duplicate `NAME` values in a `GROUP` as `RANK`/`DENSE_RANK` will give them the same values. Also `GROUP` is a keyword so you need to use double-quotes around it to be a valid identifier.

Comment: Yes, If there is duplicate values in 'Name' it won't work